# Prevent back button REFRESH on iPhone / Safari - Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, safari, mobile-safari

I have a single page application in vue with no routes. If the user goes back it does exactly what I need without changing the url. It works perfectly on every browser except safari.

When a user goes back on safari it does indeed behave the same as in any other browser **except that it refreshes the page every time**. That usualy takes 1-2 seconds while it reloads the whole app again and the page is frozen.
How on earth can I disable that behaviour?

**LE**: So apparently this happens only when using **swipe** to go back. Both on desktop and mobile safari.
If I click/tap the back button it works perfectly on both ios and mac.

Comment: It's `url` that never changes maybe, you can `e.preventDefault` & set `window.location` equals to `url`?

Comment: Yeah, I've meant url.